# Compare two lists of different strings

Tags: python, string, compare, string-comparison

I would like to compare two lists of strings, but the items in the first one will be part of the items of the second one. I give you an example:

```
list01 = ['test_item01','test_item02','truc_item03']
list02 = ['_item01','truc']
```

I would like to have something like

```
if list02 not in list01:
    #do that
```

What I really want it's that `'test_item01'` and `'_item01'` are interpreted as the same like they have a part in common.

I tried different things but nothing works.

Comment: To clarify  - you want to check that each item in `list02` is a substring of an item in `list01`, right?

Comment: The question as posed is unclear. Please follow [ask]

Comment: Yes I think that's I want :) I'm a noob in python so if by substring you mean, part of the word so yes.
And I think it will always be a prefix/suffixes or sometimes it will be the all thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
if not all(any(x in y for y in list01) for x in list02):
    print 'do that'
```

note that the functionality of all/any here guarantees good performance. Once a single superstring is found for an element of `list02`, the inner loop represented by `any` stops, and once an element of `list02` is found that has no superstring, we stop checking the rest of `list02`

Comment: this is why i love python. simple and elegant

Comment: So it is working but not completely. if in my first list I have 'truc_blabla' and in the second one '_blabla' my code is not working.
Basically I want to keep all the item of my first list except when a part of each item is in common with the second one.
Sorry I think it is not really clear...

Comment: post another data example, (similar to your first one)

Comment: Hi Pete,
I edited my first message, is it more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done also using sets intersection:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    return list(set(a) & set(b))

iSec = intersect(list01, list02)
if len(iSec) == len(list02):
    print 'contains'
else:
    print 'not contains'
```